# DataContext random function sometimes fails

Tags: linq, sorting, random

In my LINQ DataContext class I have a function which I use to sort items in a random order:

```
  [Function(Name = "NEWID", IsComposable = true)]
    public Guid Random()
    { // to prove not used by our C# code... 
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

It works correctly in some queries (calls the NEWID function), but in some it doesn't (throws a NotImplementedException). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it crashes if it is attached to an IQueryable that has already been compiled and executed on the SQL server.